# Why does git merge delete files rather than moving them?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have an old branch that I want to bring up to date. I merged from master but there are three files that have been moved and Git is saying they've been "deleted by them".

I first tried moving the files to the new location in my branch then merging but git just used the branch files and didn't attempt to merge with master.

I then tried setting:

```
git config merge.renameLimit 999999
```

but I got the same result.

Is there anything else I can do to force Git to recognise that these files have been moved rather than deleted? The filenames are the same.

Comment: Probably because the content within the is different enough that git doesn’t consider them the same.

Comment: Since the file's there under its new name, what's the actual effect of Git not declaring it a rename?

Comment: @jthill I want to merge the two files, not have one override the other.

Comment: Okay, so this is showing up as a conflict, changed by us, deleted by them, but you want changed by us, renamed by them (I gather with further changes)?

Comment: @jthill yes, something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit a (really, the) downside of Git's method of recording only snaphots and ancestry: ordinarily, Git can identify renamed files because they still look similar enough, but if you drastically change a file and also move it, there's nothing left to distinguish the result from a deleted old file and a new other file in this new location.

```
git checkout master^0                         # make a scratch commit to help Git
git mv new/path/to/file1 old/path/to/file1    # move the drastic-rewrite stuff back
git commit -m \
    'put drastically-changed-and-renamed files back where automerge can find them'

git checkout oldstuff                         # merge the helper commit to oldstuff
git merge @{1}                                # ...
git mv old/path/to/file1 new/path/to/file1    # put things in their new location
git commit --amend
```

Git's merge looks at the tips and the base. Since these files at the `master` tip look nothing at all like what they did at the merge base with `oldstuff` and have also picked up and moved since, merge doesn't see them as the same files any more.  So put them back to help Git's automerge, run the merge, move them back to their new home.

To answer your title question directly, why Git does its snapshots-and-ancestry-only histories, it's an engineering tradeoff. There's downsides no matter what you do, you've hit the downside of Git's choice.